# what is the replace function in informix for mysql now()

Tags: java, mysql, sql, informix

I have table field defined as like this  `approved_at DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND NOT NULL`.  In MySQL, when I insert to a `datetime` field I used MySQL function `now()`.  But I couldn't find any function in Informix to act like that.  Is there no such function in Informix? Or, if it exists, what is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND`.  Sometimes, you can get away with just `CURRENT`, but I don't recommend trying it.

Answer (score 2):

Jonathan Leffler is right, the informix keyword for "now" is "current"

```
UPDATE Table SET DateCol = current WHERE ... ;
```

Take a look at the [Datetime Datastructure](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/sqlrmst109.htm) too